# Failing to overlapp pictures of different sizes with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, overlapping

I am currently trying to familiarize myself with the field of computer vision. For a smaller university project I have to overlap pictures of a different size. For this I use OpenCV in Python and have tried to follow this [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html).

As you can see here, the overlapping works quite well for [colored images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjJ5w.jpg) (I used some fantasy wallpapers for that). However, I still fail with [black and white images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtrqE.png). The overlaid fingerprints should look as if they were naturally overlaid, as it does with the colored image.

Since I'm still new to the field of computer vision, I don't yet know what the problem is with the overlapping of the images and I would be happy if someone explains to me what the problem is and how to fix it. My source code is shown below.

```
background = cv2.imread("./background.png")
overlay = cv2.imread("./overlay.png")
rows_new, cols_new, channels = overlay.shape
small_img = cv2.resize(overlay,(300,300))
roi = background[0:300, 0:300]
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(small_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_or(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_or(small_img,small_img,mask = mask)
dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
background[0:300, 0:300] = dst
```

Comment: looks like the mask needs to be inverted (or *not* inverted). the overlaid fingerprint is opaque where white and transparent where black, as you can see. you probably want the opposite.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you very much, working like a charm! that was the only thing I haven't tried yet..